# taking a very efficient join between two tables in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, query-optimization

I have  big tables containing MILLIONS of data ( its too too huge).

Tables are as follows

```
Post
post_id,user_id,description,creation_date, xyz, abc ,etc

primarykey for post :post_id
partition key for Post : creation_date
index on Post : user_id

Comment:
commentid,post_id, comment_creation_date,comment_type,last_modified_date

Primary key of comment = commentid
indexed colums on Comment = commentid, postid
partition key for Comment table =  comment_creation_date
```

Note:I cant build new index not alter table schema in any way

comment type is of String

Now given a list of comment_type and a comment_creation_date range i need to find all post which has that type of comment_type.

A simple very inefficient solution will be

```
    select * from post p, comment c where c.post_id = p.post_id where c.comment_creation_date > ? and c.comment_creation_date < ?
and p.posttype IN (some list)
```

How can i optimize this query?
What if same thing by last_modified_date of comment rather then comment_date.
Note:

```
last_modified_date is NOT indexed and comment_date Is
```

Once the query succeeds i want to get all comments of one post together.
Example if post1 with c1,c2,c3

PS:I am not good at designing queries .I know IN in not good for performance.

Comment: If this isn't fast enough I'm not sure you will be able to get much faster without changing the schema in any way. The schema is a very important part of performance. You can try _SELECT * FROM post WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM comment WHERE ...)_ but I'm pretty sure the perf is going to be similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain if this would save time, but perhaps moving your Comment section to a subquery would help:

```
SELECT *
FROM Post p
JOIN (SELECT *
      FROM Comment
      WHERE comment_creation_date > ? and comment_creation_date < ?
              AND 'stringlist' LIKE '%'||comment_type||'%'
     )c
ON c.post_id = p.post_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is syntactically incorrect because it has two `where` clauses.  Also, you refer to `comment_type` in the code but to `post_type` in the code.  I'll assume the latter. You can rewrite it as:

```
select *
from post p, comment c
where c.post_id = p.post_id and
      c.comment_creation_date > ? and c.comment_creation_date < ? and
      p.posttype IN (some list)
```

Oracle has a good optimizer, so there is no reason to assume that this will optimize poorly.

Although it has no effect on performance, ANSI standard join syntax is a better way to write the query:

```
select *
from post p join
     comment c
     on c.post_id = p.post_id
where c.comment_creation_date > ? and c.comment_creation_date < ? and
      p.posttype IN (some list)
```

The optimize can decide when to do which filtering and how to do the join.  You can make either version more efficient by have an index on `comment(comment_creation_date, post_id)` and possibly on `post(post_type)` (the latter depends on how many different post types you have, something called the *selectivity* of the index).

I'm not sure what you mean by "I know IN in not good for performance."  This isn't common knowledge; please share any reference you have on this.  As far as I know, `in` with a bunch of constants should perform no worse than a bunch of expressions like `p.posttype = <value1> or p.posttype = <value2> . . .`.